# JSX conditional element in loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

How to define opening of a tag on a condition and closing of tag on another.
In the below sample I'm trying to wrap every two element on a new row. However doesn't seem to work.  Sample - https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/

```
render() {
    let menuItems = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        menuItems.push(
        {i%2 !== 0 ? <div class="row">:<>}
        <div>hi</div>
        {i%2 === 0 ? </div>:<>}
        );
    }
    return <div>{menuItems}</div>;
  }
```

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to accomplish. What is the desired output for menuItems?

Comment: `<div className="row"><div>hi</div><div>hi</div></div>
<div className="row"><div>hi</div><div>hi</div></div>
<div className="row"><div>hi</div><div>hi</div></div>`

Comment: ok so you just want that but repeated 10 times?

Comment: yes, 5X2 as formatted above

Comment: Its not possible to open a tag and closing it in different statements in React, because here they are not tags, they become objects when JSX compiles

Comment: Ok, then how else to accomplish this behavior

Comment: @meteor i have updated the fiddle with solution https://jsfiddle.net/zL9yskmh/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to revert your logic. You are trying to always insert a `<div>` but what you need to do is keep it in an array the `<div>` and push it only in the desired time.

```
render() {
    let menuItems = [];
    let hiDivs = []
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        hiDivs.push(<div>hi</div>)
        if(hiDivs.length === 2){
            menuItems.push(<div class="row">{hiDivs}</div>)
            hiDivs = []
        }
    }
    return <div>{menuItems}</div>;
}
```

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` but it's very very bad and not recommended...

Answer (score 1):

Build your data objects before rendering; this allows React to render in a declarative manner, and is flexible enough to render as many rows or columns that you'd like to add.

Also, I left the creation of the `rows` array purposely verbose; there's no reason you can't have a `numRows` variable that's used in a loop to append to the `rows` array.

https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-moser-3j51c

**Component**

```
function App() {
  const cell = "hi";
  const rows = [
    [cell, cell],
    [cell, cell],
    [cell, cell],
    [cell, cell],
    [cell, cell]
  ];

  return rows.map((row, i) => {
    return (
      <div key={i} className="row">
        {row.map((data, j) => (
          <span key={j}>{data}</span>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```

**Output**

```
hi hi
hi hi
hi hi
hi hi
hi hi
```

Since you didn't provide CSS, I swapped your inner `<div>` elements for `<span>`, so it up to you to style this appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing it this way?

```
  render() {
      let menuItems = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          const hi = <div>hi</div>
          const item = i%2 === 0
              ? <div className="row">{hi}{hi}</div>
              : hi;
          menuItems.push(item);
      }
      return <div>{menuItems}</div>;
  }
```

You might want to add a 'key' attribute as well since react will throw a warning otherwise for arrays of elements.

Comment: This doesnt return the desired output.There needs to be 2 <div>hi</div> in each row.

Comment: This renders `<div class="row"><div>hi</div></div><div>hi</div>` which is wrong

Comment: Oh missed that, but the concept is still the same just add another 'hi' element

Answer (score -2):

If your desired output is simply what is below with no other constraints (ie always two hi
s inside each row)

```
<div className="row">
   <div>hi</div>
   <div>hi</div>
</div> 
<div className="row">
   <div>hi</div>
   <div>hi</div>
</div>
..........
```

You can do:

```
let menuItems = []
for(let i = 0 ; i < 5; i++){
  menuItems.push(<div className="row"><div>hi</div><div>hi<div></div>)
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but my guess would be that the data within the `row` divs is no being generated programmatically.

Comment: That wasnt a requirement? What OP is asking for doesnt make much sense without more info, but with the limited info we have this is the easiest way to get the desired output.

Comment: I agree. The example he provided in jsfiddle is just a basic hello world and doesn't attempt to solve the problem